# DOCX file upload gives Connection timed out error in Godaddy

Tags: php, file, upload

We are having some issues while uploading docx files. It shows connection timed out message in firefox and No response received error on Chrome browser. I think , even the code was not executed, before that server gives an error response .

How i can fix this. I am on Godaddy Hosting. Do you have similar issues occured, then please suggest !

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy says you have to host your website with a private server in order to upload a .docx file to your hosted website. They claim the security permissions to accept a .docx file would let in a plethora of bad stuff to their shared server.

I say this is BS. .docx is not a rogue word processing program. It is pretty much the current Microsoft standard and it should not need special permissions. Meanwhile, we can only upload .doc and pdf files.